# Sets that are not just collections of things

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

I was wondering if there are objects that satisfy the axioms to be a set but are not what we conventionally think of when we think of sets i.e. collections of things.

I remember when I learnt that functions can be thought of as vectors, my mind was blown. I always thought of vectors as arrows and seeing how functions can be considered vectors and how you can formulate Fourier series in linear algebra was really eye opening.

I tried coming up with things that can satisfy the set axioms but I can't even get past the axiom of extensionality. Whenever I think of things belonging to other things, my mind just start thinking about sets. I guess it speaks to how general sets are.

My question is can you come up with an example that satisfies the set theory axioms (is a set) but is not what comes to mind when you normally think of a set(a collection of things)?

Comment: Define "conventionally think of" or "comes to mind."

Comment: You can derive all kinds of interesting models of set theory using toposes. Perhaps some of these models will be sufficiently counterintuitive. But when you talk about viewing functions as vectors, what you really are saying is that we can take existing things (functions to $\mathbb{R}$, for instance) and add additional structure to them - that of a vector space. When you ask for a model of set theory where the elements are not sets, you are asking a different kind of question.

Comment: See the following paper: [*On the consistency and independence of some set-theoretical axioms*](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/notre-dame-journal-of-formal-logic/volume-19/issue-1/On-the-consistency-and-independence-of-some-set-theoretical-axioms/10.1305/ndjfl/1093888220.full) by Abian/LaMacchia (1976).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I can provide an additional way of looking at the well-founded sets, which are the objects of study in a set theory that uses the axiom of foundation/regularity such as ZF. This is a fairly well-known presentation which I first encountered when learning topos theory. I’ll give the classical version since it is shorter.

We consider a relation $\prec \subseteq A^2$. As usual, we write $a \prec b$ for the assertion $(a, b) \in \prec$. We also write something like $a \prec b \prec c$ for the compound assertion $a \prec b \land b \prec c$. We call the pair $(A, \prec)$ a graph.

Definition: $\prec$ is well-founded if every non-empty subset of $A$ has an $\prec$-minimal element. Using formal logic, this is phrased as $\forall S \subseteq A (S \neq \emptyset \to \exists x \in S \forall y \in S \neg (y \prec x))$.

Note, for example, that all well-orders are well-founded (in fact, a well-order is just a well-founded strict total order).

Definition: $\prec$ is extensional if for all $a, b \in A$, if $\forall c \in A (c \prec a \iff c \prec b)$, then $a = b$.

The canonical example of a well-founded, extensional graph is $(T, \in_T)$, where $T$ is a transitive set and $\in_T = \{(x, y) \in T^2 \mid x \in y\}$. In fact, this is the only example up to bijection (this is Mostowski’s Theorem).

Now we also designate some point $r \in A$. $r$ is the “root”. The triple $(A, \prec, r)$ is known as a “pointed graph”.

A node $a \in A$ is accessible from $r$ if there is some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and some sequence $a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_n$ such that $a = a_0 \prec a_1 \prec \ldots \prec a_n = r$. The pointed graph $(A, \prec, r)$ is said to be accessible if all $a \in A$ are accessible from $r$.

We can now define a sett (the double t is intentional to distinguish from the meta-notion of set) to be an extensional, well-founded, accessible, pointed graph.

The first task is to say what it means for two setts $x, y$ to be “equal”. This is written $a \cong b$. This is straightforward. $(A, \prec, r) \cong (B \prec’, s)$ means there is a bijection $f : A \to B$ such that $f(r) = s$ and $\{(f(a), f(b)) \mid a \prec b\} = \prec’$. It can be shown that if such a bijection exists, it is necessarily unique.

Now, we must define what it means for one sett to be an “element” of another. To do this, we introduce the notion of “basic elements”.

Given a sett $(A, \prec, r)$, consider some $s \prec r$. Let $A_s = \{t \in A \mid t$ is accessible from $s\}$. Let $\prec_s= \{(a, b) \in A_s^2 \mid a \prec b\}$. Then $(A_s, \prec_s, s)$ is also an extensional, well-founded, accessible, pointed graph. The “basic elements” of $(A, \prec, r)$ are exactly the graphs which arise as $(A_s, \prec_s, s)$ for some $s \prec r$.

We know come to our definition of elementhood. Given setts $a, b$, we say $a \in’ b$ iff there is some basic element $c$ of $b$ such that $a \cong c$.

We now come to the part of the show where we relate sets and setts. Given a set $x$, the sett corresponding to it, denoted $sett(x)$, is $(T, \in_T, x)$, where $T$ is the transitive closure of $\{x\}$ and $\in_T$ is as above. Conversely, given a sett $s$, there is a unique set $x$ such that $sett(x) \cong s$. Denote this as $x = set(s)$.

Now, for the “big reveal”. We have the following theorem:

> Theorem: consider two setts $a, b$. Then $a \cong b$ if and only if $set(a) = set(b)$, and $a \in’ b$ if and only if $set(a) \in set(b)$.

The first half of this theorem is quite easy to prove - it follows from the definition of $set$ and the fact that $\cong$ is an equivalence relation. The second is less so; it requires a deeper analysis of setts.

With this result, we can essentially say that sets are just setts quotiented by $\cong$. In other words, a set is just an extensional well-founded extensional accessible graph, up to isomorphism. Also, all of this works constructively and predicatively if you use an appropriate alternate definition of well-foundedness.

Comment: Thank you! I still haven't understood even half of what you wrote but thanks anyways.